# DataGrid - Select RowStyle conditionally

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

Is it possible to conditionally apply different style to rows?

For example:
I have column "Quantity" (int), and when value is greater than 5, I'd like to set red background to whole row.
(Style triggers not working on UWP apps)

Best regards
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

At present, the `DataGrid` control which provided by CommunityToolkit does not expose the corresponding API for setting special triggers, and UWP does not support binding in `Style`.

In the definition of [DataGridRow](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGridRow.cs#L1075), there is an internal method `EnsureBackground()`, which also means that the background of the `DataGridRow` cannot be modified by `VisualTree` query (the current background color will be checked when rendering).

If you need a highly customized style, you can consider replacing the `DataGrid` with `ListView` to customize the `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks for reply. After reviewing source code of DataGrid, I was expecting reply, that it's not possible right now, but I just have some hope, that maybe some kind of workaround already exist :)

Comment: Hello, if you want this feature, you can add a feature request on [Github](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/new/choose)